# Qt 4.8.5 Understanding QMessagebox .exec() and .show()

Tags: c++, qt, show, qt4.8, qmessagebox

I'm doing a QWizard with QT 4.8.5 and in some pages I have to close some other applications and exit my program. This works fine but now I want to show a pop up message that tells the user that the programs are restarting (There are others a part of mine and mine is the last one to be closed always). The code I use to show the pop up is the next one and I place it in the validatepage of a QWizardpage:

```
  QMessageBox *msgBox1 = new QMessageBox;
    msgBox1->setWindowTitle("Title...");
    msgBox1->setIcon(QMessageBox::Information);
    msgBox1->setText(" blablablalbal bla bla bla.");
    msgBox1->setWindowModality(Qt::NonModal);
    msgBox1->show();
    QCoreApplication::processEvents(); // without this line, the show does nothing and I can't see my pop up window
```

So the thing is: With that code, When I am in that wizardpage and click to finish, it launches the QMessageBox while (behind) the program is restarting the other applications and then closes itself (with a QApplication::quit(); ) which is exactly what I want... BUT no message is shown in the pop up... I can't see the icon, the title or the text... :S I don't know why :(

Whereas when use ->exec(); instead of show, the icon, title and text are shown BUT when the pop up appears, nothing is done behind until the user closes that pop up... :S

I understand that .exec() freezes all until user closes the pop up while show doesn't...

So... how can I see the text with the show() behaviour?? I don't want the user to interact with that pop up, I just need the pop up to show up while closing all until my program closes too...

Thank you so much!

Comment: The commented last line says the `show()` call does nothing without this, but your question says the you don't see anything... can you clarify?  That seems like a contradiction.

Regardless, relevant semi-dupe:  http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.general/30706

Comment: @eclarkso Yes sorry, maybe I wxplained wrong... If I dont use the processEvents line then the pop up never shows up, its the same as if I haven't made that code... while if I put that line I can see the pop up, but this pop up is empty.. no message, no title no icon shown (And its well initialized I think as if I change the show for a exe then I see it as it should (but then it wait someone to closes it before continuing) Hope its clearer now :D

Answer (score 3):

Relevant:  http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.general/30706

In summary, `QDialog::exec()` creates a modal dialog (regardless of your `Qt::NonModal` setting) with its own event loop, and `::show()` does not.

So in your case, `::exec()` will fully render the dialog but it's blocking the rest of your background processing.  `::show()` won't block, but since it's sharing the event loop with your other code it isn't getting around to emptying the event queue (which has all of the show/layout/render events from your dialog) because of your background code.

I would try the following:

- use `::show()` not `::exec()`
- force your dialog to the front using `QDialog::raise()` and `Dialog::activateWindow()`
- (the important part) *either*

  - call `QApplication::processEvents()` within your background processing tasks (e.g., within long-running loops).
  - spawn your background processing into a thread (this may or may not be easy depending on how your code is structured) to allow the main event loop to process your dialog events.